# Angular 2: Bind observable response to input

Tags: html, forms, data-binding, angular

I have an input that looks like this in my RC4 app:

```
<div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{haserror: loginForm.controls.username.errors}">

    <label for="username">{{ 'username' | translate:{value: param} }}:</label>

    <input type="text" formControlName="username" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="off">

    <div class="input-error-feedback" *ngIf="loginForm.controls.username.errors">
       {{ 'usernameError' | translate:{value: param} }}
    </div>

</div>
```

Now I want to populate the input field by making a HTTP call to my API. I tried making an observable call and did the following:

```
value="{{accountData?.username}}"
```

That populates the form, but will not be POSTed back to the API unless I manually change the value of it.

How do I map the response I get from my API to the input so that it does?

Comment: `[(ngModel)]="accountData.username"` instead of `value` property should do the job

Comment: That gives me `Cannot read property of undefined`. I tried adding the "?" in there like I did with the interpolation, but that was not supported. Can I throw an async pipe or something in there?

Comment: you probably want to show the form when `accountData` is retrieved from the server. To eliminate this error you should use *ngIf="accountData" directive in form element. I hope it helps.

Comment: Yes! That worked just fine. Thank you!